# Microk8s on Air Gapped Computer

Tags: microk8s

Is there a way to install Microk8s on an air gapped computer. I followed the offline instructions on their website but having a squid proxy still requires an internet connection. (https://microk8s.io/docs/install-alternatives#heading--offline). I've been able to get the basic install working by downloading the appropriate docker images and modifying some of the configuration files, but when it comes to enabling add-ons, I am not able to modify the configurations because they are read-only.